# How to set vol_perc in slstatus (a suckless tool)?

Tags: c, x-dwm

I just started playing around with suckless tool "slstatus" for my dwm.
Everything is straight forward but the volume percentage.

In the config.def.h funciton, description, and arguments are:

```
vol_perc   OSS/ALSA volume in percent   mixer file (/dev/mixer)
```

The problem is I cannot find the mixer file. Any idea where I should start looking?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anyone is still interested in this but here it is anyway. One could just use the `run_command` with the following complement:

```
"amixer sget Master | tail -1 | awk '{print $5 }' | sed 's@\\(\\[\\|\\]\\)@@g'"
```

Here is an example:

```
{ run_command, "[V] %s", "amixer sget Master | tail -1 | awk '{print $5 }' | sed 's@\\(\\[\\|\\]\\)@@g'" },
```

Answer (score 0):

/dev/mixer is an ancient interface. To enable it, you have to load the snd_pcm_oss module; I believe that this module is available on the default Arch kernel. Add 'snd_pcm_oss' to your /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf file, and on rebooting /dev/mixer should show up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there another file I can refer to without loading the module?

Comment: Unfortunately, not in vanilla slstatus

Comment: With some script or just a command (using `run_command`) you can do it.